# WCF suppress deserialization of certain operation implementation parameters

Tags: wcf, serialization, wsdl

I have a WCF service that has an operation that takes any .net serializable client data.

```
[OperationContract]
void SaveMyData(long id, string name, object serializableData);

[OperationContract]
object LoadMyData(long id, string name);
```

The server doesn't need to know what the data is, it just stores it or returns what is stored.  And the server doesn't even know the types being serialized so of course this contract would result in deserialization exceptions.

**I know that I could serialize/deserialize this independently of the WCF contract**, for example:

```
[OperationContract]
void SaveMyData(long id, string name, byte[] serializedData);

[OperationContract]
byte[] LoadMyData(long id, string name);
```

But this requires additional code on the client to serialize and deserialize. I'd like to avoid that and have the client code as simple as possible.

**I know that I could create a pre-build proxy in a client dll** that would wrap the WCF calls and perform the additional serialization/deserialization. But I'd rather be able to rely on the clients generated from the WSDL.

Ideally, a `RawAttribute` could be placed on the parameters or return value which would suppress serialization/deserialization (of the universal root `object` type) and instead supply or expect an (object)byte[] (or (object)Stream?) from the operation.

```
[OperationBehavior]
public void SaveMyData(long id, string name, [Raw] object serializableData){ ... }

[OperationContract, Raw]
object LoadMyData(long id, string name);
```

I've looked at `DataContractSurrogate` and `DataContractResolver` but I'm not seeing how to achieve this. `DataContractSurrogate` seems too late in the deserialization pipeline as the type and deserialized object are already supplied. The resolver doesn't give the data, just the type info.  Neither gives information about the parameter being deserialized for which to find the `RawAttribute`.

Does WCF offer an appropriate extensibility point for this? Or a built-in way?

I would also like to know what the declared type is, as extracted from the serialized data, but that isn't necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Carlos has written a great series of WCF extensibility points [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx) and specifically around serialization [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/30/wcf-extensibility-serialization.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead to fighting WCF's serialization mechanism, you should drop one level of abstraction and work at the message level of WCF. What you're looking for is a kind of "universal" service that can accept messages from any client. Read through this old but still applicable [MSDN article on WCF Messaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163447.aspx). Toward the bottom of the article (figure 8) is sample code for a generic WCF service. That should at least give you a start in creating a service that bypasses serialization.